# Should I ask a new question (lme4 vs MCMCglmm)?

Tags: discussion

In [my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32994/lme4-vs-mcmcglmm-what-are-r-structure-g-structure-in-a-glmm), I had an answer that wasn't understandable (for me) but in the comments to that answer and also the comments to the original question, I got some very useful info, although it made me more confused ! So now I think the way forward is to post a reproducible example with `lme4` (`glmer()`) and `MCMCglmm()` operating on the same data and ask about the differences in the results (specifically about the R-structure). I have now made a reproducible example. So should I amend the question (which will make many of the comments redundant, but possibly not the one answer) or should I ask a new question ?

Comment: Just to say: I have decided to edit the question. Hope that's OK !

Comment: I think editing the question is usually the way to go (see more [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/what-is-the-best-way-to-ask-a-follow-up-or-slightly-revised-question?rq=1)), and was certainly OK in this case.

Comment: I too think this is ok in this case. Given your edits, your audience might well provide additional and useful updates. Of note, I think there's nothing wrong in first asking a theoretical question, and then a follow-up question with application on real or artificial data with different questions.